# Excel: Apply formula to each cell in column within another formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of numbers. I want to `ROUND` the numbers in each cell of the column and then take the `SUM` of the cells.

Of course this can be done by creating another column with the rounded values and then taking its sum.

Say that I have 10 cells in column A. I round them to the nearest 0 using `ROUND(A#,0)` for A1 through A10. These new values go in `B#`. Then in `B11` I have `SUM(B1:B10)`.

Is there a way to apply the `ROUND` forumla to each cell in column A within the  `SUM` function so that I do not need to create another column of values?

Comment: FYI there is a (super ugly) way to do your last MATLAB question. Was about to post before you deleted the question: `subsref(A * B, struct('type', '()', 'subs', {{':', [2 3]}}))`

Comment: @tdy. Thanks. There's actually a solution. `A * B(:, 2:end)`. Mathematically it's correct although technically it's a solution to another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an array formula - enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=SUM(ROUND(A1:A10,0))
```

For example (also shows the rounded numbers in Column B to show it works, or you can see the magic with *Formulas* > *Evaluate Formula*.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## SUMPRODUCT 'Deals' in Arrays 2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUND(A1:A10,0))
```